# React Native - How to make a view take up full space horizontally?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Here's my Main screen:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, View } from "react-native";

import Header from "../components/Header";

function WelcomeScreen(props) {
return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.background}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <View style={styles.navbar}>
        <Header> Multiplication from 0 to 9</Header>
      </View>
   </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    backgroundColor: "dodgerblue",
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  navbar: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
  },
});

export default WelcomeScreen;
```

And my header component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

function Header({ children }) {
  return <Text style={styles.text}>{children}</Text>;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontSize: 30,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
});

export default Header;
```

And this is the result:
[image: Screenshot]

If you run my code, you can see that the navbar is not taking up 100% of the width of the screen.
Note: setting width to 100 didn't work.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/upbeat-pretzels)

[image]

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, View, Text , Dimensions} from 'react-native';

import Header from './components/Header';

const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

function WelcomeScreen(props) {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.background}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <View style={styles.navbar}>
        <Header> Multiplication from 0 to 9</Header>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue',
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 24,
  },
  navbar: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    position: 'absolute',
    alignItems: 'center',
    top: 0,
    width: screenWidth
  },
});

export default WelcomeScreen;
```